# What is the Concourse (fly) CLI command to list all the available resource types?

Tags: concourse, concourse-fly, concourse-resource-types

While troubleshooting some pipelines a week ago I stumbled upon a `fly` CLI command that lists the resource types available in Concourse (i.e. for which one would not need to provide `resource_types` in the pipeline.).

Can someone help me dig out this command again?

I'll post an answer if I manage to find it again.

Comment: Have you checked it below command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for this command to list all resource types available in the concourse:

```
fly -t <target-name> workers -d
```

Here, you will get the `resource types` column, there you can check available types.